# BASH script : usage displays even if you provide a switch without argument

Tags: bash, shell

i've tried many ways to do this and I'm stumped. When i try the `sudo admpanel -a` without argument the script displays the message from the usage() method instead of the error msg i've built into it. But on the other hand if i `sudo admpanel -a FirstName` it displays me the error msg portion. If i enter `sudo admpanel -a FirstName LastName` it functions the way its supposed to. Below is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# PROGRAM NAME : admpanel.sh

PROGNAME=${0##*/}
VERSION="1.0"
SCRIPT_SHELL=${SHELL}

usage() {
  echo "Usage: ${PROGNAME} [-h|--help ] [-a|--add] [-r|--remove] [-d|--display] [-c|--check] [argument_1] [argument_2]"
}

help_message() {
    cat <<- _EOF_
    ${PROGNAME} ${VERSION}
    Add/Remove/Display user(s) on Admin Panel. Please note that the password is hardcoded.
    Please consult with the system administrator if you already don't know it.

    $(usage)

    Options:

    -h, --help      Displays help.
    -a, --add       Add user
    -r, --remove    Remove user
    -d, --display   Display all users
    -c, --check     Check specific user

    Example:

    ${PROGNAME} -a firstName lastName
    ${PROGNAME} --add firstName lastName

    ${PROGNAME} -r firstName lastName
    ${PROGNAME} --remove firstName lastName

    ${PROGNAME} -d
    ${PROGNAME} -display

    ${PROGNAME} -c firstName LastName
    ${PROGNAME} --check firstName LastName

_EOF_
}

verify() {
    echo "Are you sure you want to do this?"
    read answer
}

add_employee() {
    echo adding user
}

remove_employee() {
    echo removing user
}

display_users() {
    echo displaying users
}

check_user() {
    echo checking users
}


if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
elif [[ $USER != "root" ]]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root!"
    exit 1
elif [[ ($1 == "-h" ) || ($1 == "-help") || ($1 == "--help") ]]; then
    help_message
    exit 0
elif [[ ($1 == "-a") || ($1 == "-add") || ($1 == "--add") ]]; then
    if [[ -z "$3" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: First name and last name wasn't provided"
        echo "usage: ${PROGNAME} -a FirstName LastName" 
        exit 1  
    elif [[ (-z "$2") || (-z "$3") ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: Either first name or last name wasn't provided or both"
        echo "usage: ${PROGNAME} -a FirstName LastName"
        exit 1
    else
        read -p "Are you sure you want to continue? <y/N> " prompt
        if [[ $prompt == "y" || $prompt == "Y" || $prompt == "yes" || $prompt == "Yes" ]]; then
            add_employee
            exit 0
        else
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
elif [[ ($1 == "-r") || ($1 == "-remove") || ($1 == "--remove") ]]; then
    remove_employee
    exit 0
elif [[ ($1 == "-d") || ($1 == "-display") || ($1 == "--display") ]]; then
    display_users
    exit 0
elif [[ ($1 == "-c") || ($1 == "-check") || ($1 == "--check") ]]; then
    check_user
    exit 0
else
    echo something went wrong try again...
    exit 1
fi
```

please advise. -Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without sudo this script gives me the specific error message for a missing last name when called like that. Are you sure those arguments are making it to the script and not being eaten by sudo? What do you get if you add `printf '[%q]\n' "$@"` to the script for the error cases?

Comment: yes, the arguments are making it to the script; if its ran as super-user

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see what you get as output from the script running then.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line:

```
if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then
```

It says "less than **or equal to** 1". Therefore, the message triggers when you give it 1 argument, namely `-a`.

You should instead change it to "strictly less than":

```
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
```